# No video signal to monitor

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard, dvi

My monitor will not display any signal from my PC all of the sudden. I have verified that it is not the monitor or the video card (the monitor works on another computer, and I have tried multiple video cards). My motherboard does not have a video output, so all I have is 2 DVIs from the video card to try. When the computer boots up everything sounds normal and if i unplug and plug in the DVI while it is running the monitor will briefly act like it is coming on and then change to "digital power save" as if it doesn't get a working signal.

I have:

- made sure the monitor is on the correct source
- checked and rechecked all cables and plugs
- tried power cycling and resetting everything.

Comment: cable? or is there anything in bios? maybe reset bios to default...

Comment: How do you know it's not the video card? Did you try it in other computers? or did you try multiple cards in this computer?

Comment: As I said, I have tried multiple video cards in this computer

Answer (score 1):

Does 'resetting everything' include shorting/resetting the cmos, jumper?  A bad setting, or IRQ conflict could do this.  I'd perhaps yank SATA cables out and pull any other cards and then reset the CMOS and see if you can get display.

Comment: I did reset CMOS, but not with all the cables yanked yet